# Save history directly

Tags: office-communicator-2007

I've activated logging in Office Communicator. But the logs are not saved directly but after a while. It's a bit annoying since closing the chat window(s) will prevent the logs from being saved.

Is it possible to reduce the time frame or make communicator to save the logs directly?